# Failed to compile ./src/index.js Module not found: Can't resolve './redux/actions'

Tags: redux

I am new to react and redux and I am working on a To Do list project. I am getting the following error and I have tried what seems like everything so I am looking of help.  I have uninstalled, installed redux and i am still getting the same error.  I have moved my index file into src folder and not having any luck. Any help would be appreciated, sorry if it is a simple fix but I have spent a lot of tie before I asked.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3fS0m.png)

```
index.js

import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
import store from "./redux/store";
import { toggleTodo } from "./redux/actions";
import TodoApp from "./redux/TodoApp";

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <TodoApp />
  </Provider>,
  rootElement
);


ToDo.js

import React from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import cx from "classnames";
import { toggleTodo } from "./redux/actions";

const Todo = ({ todo, toggleTodo }) => (
  <li className="todo-item" onClick={() => toggleTodo(todo.id)}>
    {todo && todo.completed ? "+" : "-"}{" "}
    <span
      className={cx(
        "todo-item__text",
        todo && todo.completed && "todo-item__text--completed"
      )}`enter code here`
    >
      {todo.content}
    </span>
  </li>
);

export default connect(
  null,
)(Todo);
```

Not sure if there is something that I am missing.  I feel like I don't have the proper redux installed but I have uninstalled and reinstalled, so I am not sure if I am missing something.  Thanks!

Comment: Where is your action file under redux dir?

Comment: I don't have one, I thought that was not required?  I am looking into that now .

Comment: I realized that is the issue.  Working on that now thanks for pointing that out to me.  Like I said I am new to this and appreciate your help!

Comment: No worries mate